# Read a jrxml using JasperReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have read a .jrxml file and show what all sections it contains and what is contained in each section like this.Now user can add/delete them on my UI (Don't worry about tree structure I can code to show it, I just need data).

```
--Title
  --StaticText
  --Image
--PageHeader
  --Static Text
...and so on
```

My Approach

```
JasperDesign jd= JRXmlLoader.load("my.jrxml"); //Load my jrxml
if(jd.getTitle()!=null)                        //If file have Title explore it 
{
   JRBand band= jd.getTitle();
   JRElement ele[]=band.getElements();     //first get band and then all its elements
   for(JRElement x:ele)
   {
       x.getUUID();     
       // I will make a MAP here "UUID" vs "Section in which it belongs"
       //So when a user says delete image under Title I will get it's UUID
       //  tht I just stored above and delete it    
   }  
}
// I will do same for PageHeader, Detail etc
```

Am I on the right path? Is there any easy/efficient way to do the same?
Tell me if I am unclear at any step.

Comment: IMHO, it is better to use *JasperReports API* or *DynamicJasper API* or *DynamicReports API* to build report "on fly"

Comment: When I said JasperAPI I meant JasperReportAPI only. You can see I used its JasperDesign class. Anyway I edited it :)

Comment: What is a reason to read *jrxml* file?

Comment: I am making a Web UI where user will upload his jrxml file and I will show him the file's content in a hierarchical manner. Now when he selects a static field I will show all its properties like font,text,bold etc. He can Add new elements,modify/delete existing. Now in end I will give him his changed jrxml.

Comment: The *JasperReports API*, *DynamicJasper API*, *DynamicReports API* let you to build the report as you want.

Comment: You mean they give me Web based solution too.It would be great if you can give me links comparing three of them.
Also I have to make the thing I am making. I can't backoff now :(
So please if you know tell me the solution of my above prob. 
Thnx :)